# How to find child element based on a specific node in PHP?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

We can use the childNodes property,and item() function to locate a child element based on a parent node, however, if the path between the parent and the child is too long, there might have be too many childNodes->item() that is needed to be writing, like the PHP I listed below, I want to find the content inside the P tag, based on node Table, you can check the variable $sentences, I don't know if this is the only way to deal with such situation, is there any better way to do this?

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Sentence 1</p>
        </td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a>Click 1</a>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Sentence 2</p>
        </td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a>Click 2</a>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Here is my PHP code

```
$content = file_get_contents('./a.html');
$dom = new \domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

$table_list = $xpath->query('//table');
foreach($table_list as $k=>$table_node){
    $sentence1 = $table_node->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

I need to get the value inside P tag, you can see the code is really long to just get the value inside the P tag, is there any way I can shorten the code, like using

```
$sentence1 = $table_node->FIND('//tr/td/p')
```

Instead of writing childNodes->item() repeatedly?

Comment: xpath's query lets you specify a context node. e.g. `foreach($xpath->query('//table') as $table) { foreach($xpath->query('//p', $table) { ... }}`, and the inner query will start its search at each particular `<table>` node, instead of the entire overall document.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = file_get_contents('./a.html');
$dom = new \domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

$table_list = $xpath->query('//table/tr/td/p');

$sentences = array();
foreach($table_list as $k=>$table_node){
    $sentences[] = $table_node->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply do this: `$xpath->query('/table//p')`. It will return all p elements that are a direct or indirect child of the table element at the root.